# Creating straight line in matrix

Tags: matrices

I need to add some straight lines inside a matrix to indicate labeling of rows, like this:

[image: screenshot]

How do I do that?

Answer (score 8):

Leaders is optimal for this situation. [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides `\hdotsfor{<cols>}` that draws a dotted leader across `<cols>` columns. It is also possible to overlay a row number by setting that specific row twice (once with `\hdotsfor` and once with a row number, say). I've also added `\numberrowwithline{<cols>}{<stuff>}` that draws a line (instead of dots) as a dash leader, and inserts `<stuff>` in the middle of `<cols>` columns. The default space on either side is `\fboxsep`.

The following is a modified example, taken from Herbert's [`mathmode` document](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath

\newcommand{\numberrowwithline}[2]{%
  \multicolumn{#1}c%
    {\xleaders\hbox{-\kern-1pt}\hfill\kern\fboxsep%
        #2\hspace*{\fboxsep}%
        \xleaders\hbox{-\kern-1pt}\hfill\kern0pt%
        }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \underline{A}=\left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & 0 \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 \\
    0 & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
    \hdotsfor{7} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    \hdotsfor{7} \\[-\normalbaselineskip]
        \multicolumn{7}{c}{\colorbox{white}{\ $R_n$\ }} \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        \numberrowwithline{7}{R_i} \\
    0 & \ldots & 0 & a_{n-2,n-3} & a_{n-2,n-2} & a_{n-2,n-1} & 0 \\
    0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & q_{n-1,n-2} & a_{n-1,n-1} & a_{n-1,n} \\
    0 & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & a_{n,n-1} & a_{nn}
  \end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

With the addition of [`xhfill`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xhfill) you can go crazy with the colours and types of leaders. See the [`xhfill` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xhfill/xhfill-doc.pdf) for the different styles of lines as a sample.

Answer (score 6):

```
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\hrulefill R_2 \hrulefill}
```

if it is a 3 column array

Answer (score 0):

With `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}


\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceArray}{cc@{\hspace{7mm}}ccc}
a_{11} &a_{12} & \Cdots[shorten=5pt] & a_{1,n-1} & a_{1n} \\
\Cdots[line-style=solid] && R_2 & \Cdots[line-style=solid] \\
&& \vdots \\
\Cdots[line-style=solid] && R_n & \Cdots[line-style=solid] \\
\end{bNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]